# Introduction to algorithms (CLRS) Problem 33-1 Newton's method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, algorithms, newton-raphson

## Here is the original problem

Gradient descent iteratively moves closer to a desired value (the minimum) of a function. Another algorithm in this spirit is known as Newton’s method, which is an iterative algorithm that finds the root of a function. Here, we consider Newton’s method which, given a function $f : ℝ → ℝ$, finds a value $x^*$ such that $f(x^* ) = 0$. The algorithm moves
through a series of points $x^{(0)}, x^{(1)}, …$. If the algorithm is currently at a point $x^{(t)}$, then to find point $x^{(t+1)}$, it first takes the equation of the line tangent to the curve at $x=x^{(t)}$,

$y = f′(x^{(t)})(x – x^{(t)}) + f(x^{(t)})$.

It then uses the $x$-intercept of this line as the next point $x^{(t+1)}$.

**a**. Show that the algorithm described above can be summarized by the update rule

$$x^{(t+1)}=x^{(t)}-\dfrac{f(x^{(t)})}{f'(x^{(t)})}$$

We restrict our attention to some domain $I$ and assume that $f′(x) ≠ 0$ for
all $x ∈ I$ and that $f''(x)$ is continuous. We also assume that the starting
point $x^{(0)}$ is sufficiently close to $x^{*}$, where “sufficiently close” means
that we can use only the first two terms of the Taylor expansion of $f(x^{*})$
about $x^{(0)}$, namely

$$f(x^{\ast})=f(x_0)+f'(x^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})+\frac{1}{2}f''(\gamma^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})^2\qquad(33.34)$$

where $γ^{(0)}$ is some value between $x^{(0)}$ and $x^*$. If the approximation in
equation (33.34) holds for $x^{(0)}$, it also holds for any point closer to $x^*$.

**b**. Assume that the function $f$ has exactly one point $x^*$ for which $f(x^*) =
0$. Let $ε^{(t)} = |x^{(t)} – x^*|$. Using the Taylor expansion in equation
(33.34), show that

$\epsilon^{(t+1)}=\dfrac{|f''(\gamma^{(t)})|}{|2f'(\gamma^{(t)})|}\epsilon^{(t)}$

where $γ^{(t)}$ is some value between $x^{(t)}$ and $x^*$.

## Here is where I'm stuck

I now hope to solve the subproblem **b**. I hope to prove the case when $t=0$. Then I calculate $\epsilon^{(1)}$, I can get

$\begin{aligned}
\epsilon^{(1)}&=|x^{(1)}-x^{\ast}|\\
&=\left|x^{(0)}-\dfrac{f(x^{(0)})}{f'(x^{(0)})}-x^{\ast}\right|\\
&=\left|x^{(0)}+\dfrac{f'(x^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})+\frac{1}{2}f''(\gamma^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})^2-f(x^{\ast})}{f'(x^{(0)})}-x^{\ast}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}f''(\gamma^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})^2-f(x^{\ast})}{f'(x^{(0)})}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{f''(\gamma^{(0)})(x^{\ast}-x^{(0)})^2}{2f'(x^{(0)})}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{f''(\gamma^{(0)})}{2f'(x^{(0)})}\right|(\epsilon^{(0)})^2\\
&=\left|\dfrac{f''(\gamma^{(0)})}{2f'(\gamma^{(0)})}\right|\epsilon^{(0)}&\qquad(?)\\
\end{aligned}$

However, the step $(?)$ I don't know how to get. This means I need to prove that $f'(x^{(0)})=f'(\gamma^{(0)})\epsilon^{(0)}$, can anyone please prove this?

Comment: (33.34) is exact as written- it's important to understand this form of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Your doubt in that last step is justified. The square of the quadratic convergence has to remain, and the expansion and intermediate points remain decoupled. So you get the constant $C=\frac{M_2}{2m_1}$ in the relation $ϵ_{n+1}=Cϵ_{n}^2$, where $M_2=\max_{x\in I}|f''(x)|$ and $m_1=\min_{x\in I}|f'(x)|$ for a suitable interval $I$ around the root.